# DWIN display ,some "phantom code" is running and is blocking the display?

Tags: display

I'm experiencing with a DWIN display **DMG48320F035_01WTC** by interface board **HDL6625V2A**.
The DWIN support sent me a project to compare with mine;after loaded(with SD card method)
the DWIN project worked,and before showing any image it played 3 beeps a couple of seconds after power on.Ok .I guess that it means there is some code running before loading background image.
After replacing DWIN project with my old project I still have the beeps from somewhere,and my touch controls are reacting *only before beeps start*,then the display  freezes on the last background image present on it and touch controls look inactive.
Furthermore I do not have TX UART comunication with any terminal
The display keeps sending **5A A5 04 80 03 00 1F**   ,any command sent by terminal has no effect.Same behaviour with DWIN terminal or Realterm,Teraterm..
Please ,can you help me?
Thanks.
Diego.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to reduce the image quality when generate icl file